# How can I get redirected to another screen onPress the button?

Tags: react-native

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, View, Text} from "react-native";
import Member from "./Signup"
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createAppContainer} from "react-navigation"

export default function App (){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello App Sean</Text>
        <Button 
        onPress = {()=>navigation.navigate("Member")}
        title="Redirect"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text} from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

export default class Member extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Sign Up Sean!!!</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

the above is my main file. My Member component in Signup file is the second one. I want to have my button clicked and get redirected to Sign-up screen. How can I do so?
I have been googling all day but it seems like I haven't found a piercing solution yet.
Please help me out.

Comment: if both components are part of navigation ie stacknavigation, you can use this.props.navigation.navigate("Member")

Comment: can you show the stack, that you created? or error or anything more, this is less to say anything, so far i think the navigation variable is missing

Answer (score 0):

A bit of off-topic, but I would recommend you to use [React-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/quick-start) (for RN) and combined with useHistory hook you will not come up with these problems. A basic usage of `replace() or push()` methods will manipulate the navigation between routes easily.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create a stack navigator, let's call it navigator.js :

```
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

  import Register from '../screens/registration';
  import bottomNavigator from './bottomNavigator';
  import Login from '../screens/login';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    }
  },
  Register: {
    screen: Register,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
  }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: bottomNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
  }
  }
});



const CurrentScreen = createAppContainer(RootStack);


export default CurrentScreen;
```

and then simply use this in your functions :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Your Page Title');
```

i hope this is what you're looking for.